# Horse Riding Combat

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

In Warband's mounted combat, we can choose attack directions by moving our mouse. This was absent in the original M&B. I tried warband after playing M&B for a long time and this game mechanic is too tough for me. About 100 in game days and I still haven't gotten use to it.

Is there a way to change that to original M&B one? or perhaps a mod?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the direction from the oncoming attack, invert the axis Y of the mouse. Swipe right for right attack and vice versa. Can be done at the options menu.